# Adjusting object@pp$X in lme4

Tags: r, lme4

I'm testing some fixed coefficients in an lmer model, but need to use that model in further process (calculating the contribution of each variable), so hence need to change some parts of the lmerMod model.

One I'm struggling with is changing object@pp$X due to the following error message

Error: invalid replacement: reference class field ‘X’ is read-only

Reproducible example below:

```
#Load package and data
library(lme4)
data(iris)

#build the model
mod<-lmer(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length + offset(Petal.Width*1) + (1|Species),data=iris)

fixef(mod) #not showing the offset coefficient

#apply changes to mod to get fixef(mod) to work with new coefficient
mod@beta <- c(mod@beta,1) #because model was offset by 1*Petal.Width
mod@pp$X <- matrix(data.frame(mod@pp$X, iris["Petal.Width"])) #causes the error

#check fixef:
fixef(mod) # should have Petal.Width at the end with a value of 1
```

To Note:

[fixef]:(https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/lmer.R#L876)! has two calls within it's function:

1. is to object@beta (already changed successfully);
2. is to getME(object,"X"):(https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/lmer.R#L1932).

I am open to alternative ways of getting to the fixef coefficients with their variable names (being able to adjust the lmerMod directly)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of the slot `pp` in the object `mod` is `merPredD`:

```
library(lme4)
data(iris)
mod <- lmer(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length + offset(Petal.Width*1) + (1|Species),data=iris)
class(slot(mod,"pp"))

[1] "merPredD"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lme4"
```

This class of `lme4` objects can be generated by the `merPredD` command of `lme4`.
Here is an example for generating a `merPredD` object using the same parameters of `mod@pp`:

```
obj1 <- merPredD(X=mod@pp$X, Zt=mod@pp$Zt, Lambdat=mod@pp$Lambdat, Lind=mod@pp$Lind, 
         theta=mod@pp$theta, n=nrow(mod@pp$X))
class(obj1)
```

Using `mod@pp <- obj1` we get no error messages and we can replace the `mod@pp` object with `obj1`.  
Following this way we can for example change the second column of `mod@pp$X`:

```
mod <- lmer(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length + offset(Petal.Width*1) + (1|Species),data=iris)
Xold <-  Xnew <- mod@pp$X
set.seed(1)
Xnew[,2] <- rnorm(nrow(Xold))
mod@pp <- merPredD(X=Xnew, Zt=mod@pp$Zt, Lambdat=mod@pp$Lambdat, Lind=mod@pp$Lind, 
         theta=mod@pp$theta, n=nrow(mod@pp$X))
head(cbind(Xold[,2], mod@pp$X[,2]))

#######
  [,1]       [,2]
1  1.4 -0.6264538
2  1.4  0.1836433
3  1.3 -0.8356286
4  1.5  1.5952808
5  1.4  0.3295078
6  1.7 -0.8204684
```

We can also add a third column to `mod@pp$X`:

```
mod <- lmer(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length + offset(Petal.Width*1) + (1|Species),data=iris)
Xnew <- as.matrix(data.frame(mod@pp$X, iris["Petal.Width"]))
colnames(Xnew) <- c(colnames(mod@pp$X),"Petal.Width")
mod@pp <- merPredD(X=Xnew, Zt=mod@pp$Zt, Lambdat=mod@pp$Lambdat, Lind=mod@pp$Lind, 
         theta=mod@pp$theta, n=nrow(mod@pp$X))
head(mod@pp$X)

#######
  (Intercept) Petal.Length Petal.Width
1           1          1.4         0.2
2           1          1.4         0.2
3           1          1.3         0.2
4           1          1.5         0.2
5           1          1.4         0.2
6           1          1.7         0.4
```